# Rails: form_for with field for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i've got model with:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :description, :img_url, :name, :price, :quantity, :tags

  serialize :tags, Hash
end
```

and try to make form for it

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :"tags[:condition]_new", "new" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :"tags[:condition]", "New", checked: true %>
    <%= f.radio_button :"tags[:condition]", "Used" %> 
<% end %>
```

unfortunately it rails raise

> undefined method `tags[:condition]' for #Product:0x007fd26d965810>
>   <%= f.radio_button :"tags[:condition]", "Used" %>  <-- ONLY FOR 2ND LINE. first is okey. WHY?!

and I can't figure out why its trying to put method on it. Has anyone  idea how to make proper field for hash value?
+ Why it fails only on 2nd f.radio_button and i passes first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not setting any value for 2nd radio button, try this and it will work fine.

```
<%= f.radio_button :"tags[:condition]", "Used", checked: false %>
```

As if you will not pass any value, then `FormHelper` class will call `'name[:condition]'` method on `@product` to get its corresponding value, though there is no method defined in the model it raises exception.